# Variants of VGA connectors

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, vga

Recently, I bought a replacement for an old VGA cable. The original one looked like this:
[image]
The new one looks like this:
[image]

I have Ubuntu OS in my PC. When I use the old (blue) VGA cable, it detects the monitor and the resolution properly. But, when I connect the new one (black), Ubuntu says that the maximum resolution is 1024x768 although I have got a full HD resolution in my monitor.
Why is the difference? Are those two connectors different in functionality?

Comment: Well the black one is missing a pin in the center row. So they are not the same cable spec.

Comment: According to Wikipedia [VGA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector), the missing pin is pin 9 (Extended Display Identification Data). There is a link for more information at the bottom of the page. "The EDID data structure includes manufacturer name and serial number, product type, phosphor or filter type, **timings supported by the display, display size**, luminance data and (for digital displays only) pixel mapping data." Such function is probably necessary for your monitor.

Comment: The connector I am using has no pins missing. I just gave a picture to show the shape of the connector. Maybe that pin is disconnected? If that is the case, I am curious to know why are such cables available till now?